# How can i set-up VIOs multiple VLANs in our p770 box?

Tags: networking, aix, vlan

There's a requirement setup needs to address to our pSeries box.  We have one p770 box intended to setup UAT and Development VM Clients, but the requirement is to set different VLANs per Environment (UAT & Dev).

Also a separation of VLANs with applications and databases, it will be assigned by specific VLAN ids by our LAN Team.

#### Questions

- How can this be done in VIOs? The old setup of our p6 box was a single VLAN which configured in our VIOs thru SEA.
- How can we assign different VLANs in the SEA, or is it correct that its being configured via SEA or there is any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options.

1. you could create multiple VIO servers and run DEV and UAT off different VIOs
2. you can create multiple SEA's on VIO servers and assign different physical adapters to each of the SEAs
3. you can assign multiple VLANs to the same SEA as long as the network side is set up for it (referred to as VLAN tagging usually)
4. other stuff I've not thought of straight away

There's no single right answer, it depends on a number of other factors.  I strongly recommend you read the Red Books on PowerVM (VIO) because they cover the different scenarios.

[IBM PowerVM Virtualization Introduction and Configuration](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247940.pdf) is the best starting place.

Comment: Hi, thanks @EightBitTony, i think i can go on #2.  Will read this Redbook now.